# How can I put together the option selected with the input inserted by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, user-input

I'm beginning to study web development, just html, css and bootstrap so far... And training the things that I've learned, I just got stucked with the following situation:

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input required type="email" name="" id="email" class="form-control">

     <div class="input-group-append">
          <select name="" id="kasp">
               <option value="@gmail.com">@gmail.com</option>
               <option value="@homail.com">@homail.com</option>
               <option value="@yahoo.com.br">@yahoo.com.br</option>
          </select>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Using only this, would it be possible to put together what was typed in the  with what was selected?

I guess that some javascript may be necessary to do it, but I'm also curious to know if there's some way of doing it without js, so what do you tell me? I haven't started with javascript yet, but anyway, how would it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the server script when you submit the form. But if you want to do it on the client, you have to use JavaScript.

Use `.value` to get the values of each input, and `+` to concatenate strings.

```
var full_email = document.getElementById("email").value + document.getElementById("kasp").value
```